# Tips on using @sys.date-period to resolve consistent values?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm experimenting with an intent that would work with relative dates.

I could imagine the user saying something like

> Which projects will end in the next 60 days?

or

> Which projects will end within 60 days?

It could end up being more complicated than that, but I'll keep it simple for this question.

In those 2 cases, the entity is @sys.date-period.

The first resolves to `"in the next 60 days"`

The second resolves to `"within 60 days"`

Is there a better way to do this so that the fulfillment doesn't have to be coded to parse and interpret "in the next" and "within" etc?